# Append frequency value from data

Tags: r

I have a data set that look like this

```
XDATA 
SAMPN   HHSIZE    TOTVEH
1          2        3
2          6        4
2          6        4
5          1        3
5          1        3
5          1        3
```

How can i add an extra column for lets say `SAMPN` frequency so i can look like this:

```
XDATA 
SAMPN   HHSIZE    TOTVEH   FREQ
1          2        3        1
2          6        4        2
2          6        4        2
5          1        3        3
5          1        3        3
5          1        3        3
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share a bit about what you have tried and why it isn't working?  this is known as a "split-apply-combine" strategy and is well documented in R.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to @Ricardo's answer for base R (which uses `tapply` and `merge`) is to use `ave`:

```
within(XDATA, {
  FREQ <- ave(SAMPN, SAMPN, FUN = length)
})
#   SAMPN HHSIZE TOTVEH FREQ
# 1     1      2      3    1
# 2     2      6      4    2
# 3     2      6      4    2
# 4     5      1      5    3
# 5     5      1      5    3
# 6     5      1      5    3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(data.table)
XDATA <- data.table(XDATA)

XDATA[, FREQ := .N, by=SAMPN]
XDATA
   SAMPN HHSIZE TOTVEH FREQ
1:     1      2      3    1
2:     2      6      4    2
3:     2      6      4    2
4:     5      1      3    3
5:     5      1      3    3
6:     5      1      3    3
>
```

#### For BASE `R` - see @Ananda Mahto's solution

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I dont know if a monster, it was just two lines, but I do like your base solution better

Answer (score 0):

```
XDATA <- data.table(
SAMPN = c(1,2,2,5,5,5),
HHSIZE = c(2,6,6,1,1,1),
TOTVEH = c(3,4,4,5,5,5)
)

XDATA[, COUNT := 1]
XDATA[, FREQ := sum(COUNT), by = c('SAMPN','HHSIZE','TOTVEH')]

#SAMPN HHSIZE TOTVEH COUNT FREQ
#1:     1      2      3     1    1
#2:     2      6      4     1    2
#3:     2      6      4     1    2
#4:     5      1      5     1    3
#5:     5      1      5     1    3
#6:     5      1      5     1    3
```

Comment: nice, but no need for `sum(count)`.   You could use `length(<any col name>)`, but even easier is data.table's built in `.N`.  Have a look at `?data.table` for documentation on all of these (ie, `.N`, `.I`, `.GRP`, etc)

Comment: `length` wouldn't have helped in this case because all the columns are in the by variable. .N looks good though.

Comment: yep, if all of the columns are in `by`, then you would need a new column to track the length, and thats exactly what .N is for ;)    Why all the columns in `by` though?  Only `SAMPN` is needed (unless I misread the questino)

Comment: I assumed the OP wants the frequency for the combination of observations. Maybe I misread the question then :)